# How to define a trilinear regression model in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, linear-regression, least-squares

I am trying to fit a trilinear model to my observation. The observation values look like A:

```
A = array([[  4.18680470e-01,   2.27554169e+00,   1.88600000e+02,    3.40000000e+00],
   [  2.64688814e-01,   2.27554169e+00,   1.88600000e+02,    3.40000000e+00],
   [  5.65145800e-03,   2.24129739e+00,   1.74300000e+02,    3.40000000e+00],
   ..., 
   [ -9.28651988e-01,   1.72997429e+00,   5.37000000e+01,    2.00000000e+00],
   [ -6.55695184e-01,   1.72997429e+00,   5.37000000e+01,    2.00000000e+00],
   [ -5.03678652e-01,   1.72591163e+00,   5.32000000e+01,    2.00000000e+00]])
```

I was able to do a linear regression with curve_fit:

```
def func(data, a,b,c):
    return data[:,0] + data[:,1]*a + data[:,2]*b + c
guess0 = (0.821,   0.00405,   0.955)
params, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, A[:,:3], A[:,3],guess0)
```

now I am trying trilinear model with least square approach. "a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c, R1, R2" are the coefficients that I want to solve for. "guess0" is the initial values for coefficients. The regression should also calculate R1 and R2 which is the difficult part for me to define. The code that I came up with is like below:

```
def residuals(A,guess):
    a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c, R1, R2 = guess
    for ii in range (len(A[:,0])):
        if A[:,2][ii] < R1:
            return A[:,0][ii] + a1*A[:,1][ii] + b1*A[:,2][ii] + c - A[:,3][ii]
        if (A[:,2][ii] >= R1 and A[:,2][ii] <= R2):
            return A[:,0][ii] + a1*log10(R1) + a2*A[:,1][ii] - a2*log10(R1) + b1*R1 + b2*A[:,2][ii] - b2*R1 + c - A[:,3][ii]
        if A[:,2][ii] > R2:
            return A[:,0][ii] + a1*log10(R1) + a2*log10(R2) - a2*log10(R1) + a3*A[:,1][ii] - a3*log10(R2) + b1*R1 + b2*R2 - b2*R1 + b3*A[:,2][ii] - b3*R2+ c - A[:,3][ii]

guess0 = [-1.0,0.0,-0.5,0.00405,0.00405,0.00405,0.0,120,160]
pwithout,cov,infodict,mesg,ier=optimize.leastsq(residuals, A,guess0,full_output=True)
```

the error says:

```
...   
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 369, in leastsq
shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 20, in _check_func
res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))

File "<ipython-input-65-ca078a899876>", line 4, in residuals
if A[:,2][ii] < R1:

IndexError: too many indices
```

I am sure that it should be defined differently.

Comment: lestsq has a different call signature; why not use curve_fit as before?

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is with defining trilinear regression function. I am not sure how to solve for R1 and R2. 
I can use curve_fit if my function works fine